# Heroku - Application Deploy Error

Tags: node.js, heroku

Many thanks for any help.

Hi all,

like every beginners, i also created some simple app using NodeJs and Angularjs and trying to deploy it on Heroku. really don't know how, read some heroku docs. understand as much as i can. then tried to deploy it. all went very well but finally gives me Application error.

What i did is.!
 i clone my own repo from https://github.com/suriyaJaay/Its_Jaay_profile_With_Mr_Mrs_NodeAngular.git

```
 myprojectFolder
    public
       --app.js
       --index.html
    LICNCE
    server.js
    package.json
```

[cmd showed this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0CXu.png)
any clear guidance?

thanks in advance

Comment: Logs does not show any errors, what is your problem?

Comment: that's what my problem. it does't show errors. but if tried to open my heroku app url it show application error

Comment: You need to watch you heroku application logs (logs you posted are deploy logs). In heroku CLI : `heroku logs`

Comment: Yes you have to write `heroku logs` into the console you deployed your app from and it will show you all log we need to help you

Comment: guys can you tell me .. 


"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" what it means?